# FileInputStream returns null

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I have two methods, both using FileInputStream Objects.
The First one returns expected value. This method works fine.
But the Second method returns nothing. The value passed to the second method is not null.
I need to get the hexadecimal format of the files passed to methods.
Why is it so? Kindly Explain.
Here is my code

```
public String binaryFile1(File file1){
        try{
        stringBuilder1=new StringBuilder();
        is1=new FileInputStream(file1);
        while(b!=-1){
            counter++;
            b=is1.read();
            String s = Integer.toHexString(b).toUpperCase();
        if (s.length() == 1) {
            stringBuilder1.append('0');
        }
            if(counter%5==0){
               stringBuilder1.append(s).append("\n");
               counter=0;
            }else
                stringBuilder1.append(s).append(' ');

        }
        is1.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return stringBuilder1.toString();
}


public String binaryFile2(File file2){
        try{
        stringBuilder2=new StringBuilder();
        is2=new FileInputStream(file2);
        while(b!=-1){
            counter++;
            b=is2.read(); //Here b does not get any content assigned.
            String s = Integer.toHexString(b).toUpperCase();
        if (s.length() == 1) {
            stringBuilder2.append('0');
        }
            if(counter%5==0){
               stringBuilder2.append(s).append("\n");
               counter=0;
            }else
                stringBuilder2.append(s).append(' ');
        }
        is2.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return stringBuilder2.toString(); //Here stringBuilder2 is null
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of b exactly?

Comment: There are no methods of `FileInputStream` that can return null. The only problem here is your incorrect try/catch structure.

Comment: try-catch structures are working properly. Elliot Frisch rightly caught the problem

Comment: Your try-catch structure are *not* 'working properly': they are incorrect, and they are causig this problem. If you get an exception, you are dereferencing a variable that is only assigned in the try block. Code that depends on the success of code in a  try block should be inside the same try block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `b` is shared and you don't reset it after `binaryFile1` it's still -1 at the start of `binaryFile2`. I suggest you use,

```
int b;
while ((b = is2.read()) != -1) {
  // ...
}
```

**Edit**

It is important to close your resources when you're done. I also suggest you try and limit variable scope as much as possible. Using [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) you could write `binaryFile2` like

```
public String binaryFile2(File file) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int counter = 0;
    try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        int b;
        while ((b = is.read()) != -1) {
            counter++;
            String s = Integer.toHexString(b).toUpperCase();
            if (s.length() == 1) {
                sb.append('0');
            }
            sb.append(s);
            if (counter % 5 == 0) {
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                counter = 0;
            } else {
                sb.append(' ');
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: what if he calls binaryFile2(filename2) first and binaryFile1(filename2) after it, won't the same error occur again. I think he must initialize "int b" within both the methods.What do you think?

Comment: Rishi Prakash even your suggestion is very much valid.